# Transforming line into polygon with Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, polygonize, geometry-generator

I would like to turn my line into polygon in the symbology.

I found some hint here: https://anitagraser.com/2017/04/08/a-guide-to-geometry-generator-symbol-layers/ but I am not sure of the expression, which should be included.

I tried something like this, but the fill is not visible at all. I've got a line only.

[image]

How can I make fill for these enclosed lines?

Comment: Please provide the expression you use to create the polygon. If you don't have one, then there's your error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume there is a polyline layer `"line"`, see image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `RMT > Symbology > Single Symbol > Line > Geometry Generator`

Use the following code `make_polygon($geometry)` in the *"Geometry Generator"*-field and change the *Geometry Type* into 'Polygon/MultiPolygon'.

[image: result1]

Additionally try `convex_hull($geometry)` that will produce a [Convex hull](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Convex_hull).

[image: result2]

*Note:* Mind the forms/shape/guise of your lines.

P.S.: I can suggest inspecting the *geometry* menu in the `'Expression Dialog'`, see image below

[image: geoemtry_tab]

Comment: Perfect!  It was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Which one did you use `convex_hull()` or `make_polygon()`?

Comment: I used convex_hull()

Comment: make_polygon is also fine, I've checked it